# Choose if array element repeats itself twice -- Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

There is a javascript array

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5];
```

I want to choose elements that repeats twice. In this case its  `2` and `3`. and i want attach them into a variable.

```
var a = 2, b = 3;
```

As far as i know there is no built-in function to do that job. How can i do that. Thanks.

Comment: Make an effort to solve the problem (and to research it, I'm quite certain this has been asked and answered). If you can't find a previous question on it and can't make your own code work, post a question showing your attempt and asking a specific question about it.

Comment: Exactly twice, or at least twice?

Comment: is the array (always) sorted?

Comment: @Oriol for my task, its "at least twice"  because i am sure they wont be a triple.

Comment: This can be done, but it would be more in line with general practice to put them in another array, not in separate variables.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i am looking for easiest way or a built-in funtion. I already looked for other questions

Comment: @WebberDepor: Well, you may not have found it (there are > 10M questions), but [it is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` to get the values that occur twice.

```js
var arr  = [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5];

var dups = arr.filter ( (v,i,a) => a.indexOf(v) < i );

console.log(dups);
```

In comments you stated you would only have doubles, but no values that occur more than twice. Note that the above would return a value more than once, if the latter would be the case.

This returns the values in an array, which is how you should work. To put them in separate values can be done as follows:

```
var [a, b, ...others] = dups;
```

...but you would have to know how many variables to reserve for that, and it does not make your further program any easier. JavaScript has many nice functions (methods) for arrays, so you should in fact leave them in an array.

Comment: See [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in function to do that indeed.

You will have to loop thought the array and keeping track of the number of occurrences of the elements, while building a response array.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter a sorted array.

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5],
    repeats = arr.filter(function (a, i, aa) {
        return aa[i - 1] === a;
    });

console.log(repeats);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most simple way to do this is the following:

```
var dups = [];

var arr = [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5];

arr.forEach(function (v, i, a){
  delete arr[i];
  if (arr.indexOf(v) !== -1){
    dups.push(v);
  }
});

console.log(dups);
```

It's destructive however.